# Windows - Can console output inadvertently cause a system beep?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console, beep

I have a C# console application that logs a lot to the console (using `Trace`). Some of the stuff it logs is the compressed representation of a network message (so a lot of that is rendered as funky non-alphabetic characters).

I'm getting system beeps every so often while the application is running. Is it possible that some "text" I am writing to the console is causing them?

(By system beep, I mean from the low-tech speaker inside the PC case, not any kind of Windows sound scheme WAV)

---

If so, is there any way to disable it for my application? I want to be able to output any possible text without the it being interpreted as a sound request.

Comment: please edit your question rather than adding an answer. several answers have indicated how yo do this without inspecting every packet but are inherently a machine level issue. ultimately outputting raw bytes to the console is a bad idea since the console, roughly speaking, expects text

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to show the binary data in a hex dump instead of just blasting it all out to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want if to beep, you'll either have to replace the 0x7 character before outputting it, or disable the "Beep" device driver, which you'll find in the Non-Plug and Play Drivers section, visible if you turn on the Show Hidden Devices option. Or take the speaker out.

Answer (score 19):

That's usually caused by outputting character code 7, CTRL-G, which is the BEL (bell) character.

The first thing I normally do when buying a new computer or motherboard is to ensure the wire from the motherboard to the speaker is not connected. I haven't used the speaker since the days of Commander Keen (and removing that wire is the best OS-agnostic way of stopping the sound :-).

Comment: I wouldnt do that. The speaker is your first tool to diagnose hardware problems. when the computer just wont turn on

Comment: And on that one day in a million, I'll reconnect the wire (or more likely just upgrade to the latest and greatest :-).

Comment: It might be impractical to gouge the hardware of all users :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound
```

set the "Beep" key to "no".

Answer (score 4):

absolutely, if you output ASCII control code "Bell" (0x7) to a console, it beeps.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you check the input for BELL characters, it may still beep. This is due to font settings and unicode conversion. The character in question is [U+2022](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm), Bullet.

Raymond Chen [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/04/1411080.aspx):

> In the OEM code page, the bullet character is being converted to a
>   beep. But why is that?
>
> What you're seeing is MB_USEGLYPHCHARS in reverse. Michael Kaplan
>   discussed MB_USEGLYPHCHARS a while ago. It determines whether certain
>   characters should be treated as control characters or as printable
>   characters when converting to Unicode. For example, it controls
>   whether the ASCII bell character 0x07 should be converted to the
>   Unicode bell character U+0007 or to the Unicode bullet U+2022. You
>   need the MB_USEGLYPHCHARS flag to decide which way to go when
>   converting to Unicode, but there is no corresponding ambiguity when
>   converting from Unicode. When converting from Unicode, both U+0007 and
>   U+2022 map to the ASCII bell character.

Answer (score 1):

\b in output string will cause beep, if not disabled on the OS level.